# Save files with url rewrite

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, url-rewriting, gd

I have url rewrite on my server and my question is how to save files. I've tried to use this function, but it just doesn't work:

```
public function Upload($filename){
    $this->displayError();
    ob_clean();
    if(imagepng($this->object, "/".$filename.".png"))die("OK");
    else die("Error!");
    imagedestroy($this->object);
    die();
}
```

And then calling it like this:

```
$image = new Image(ImageShow::getImgSource(), FALSE); // This is working
if(strtolower($data['filter']) != 'normal')$image->ApplyFilter($data['filter']); //Still no error
$image->Upload(Core::RandomString(32)); // dies Error :(
```

Comment: You know that the code after if, else won't be reached?

Comment: @Robert Yes, i know. I just placed this to check if saving fails and it returns Error.